# how to connect my react app on my computer to mysql database on godaddy

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I have a react.js app, made in visual studio code. its a very basic app that is just a 'login' or 'register' page. I want this react app to be connected to my existing database on godaddy, its a mysql database. I have a connection to the database from a previous website but that connection is written in php, i want to know if its possible to connect this using react.js. this is a social network, so the database already has users and information in it, so i want the react app to be connected to it, im trying to change from a php based website to a react based website.

Comment: This has nothing to do with React. React is client-side app. MySQL connection should be performed on server side.

Comment: See my answer below. I would point out though, that maybe this is the kind of thing you should be thinking about _before_ choosing the technology to re-implement your site. Or at least it should be part of the decision making process, rather than an afterthought.

Answer (score 1):

You still need some server-side code available which will make the connection to the database.

You cannot make a connection to the database with JavaScript. (Even if you could, it would not be secure because you'd have to store the database credentials in the JS code, and of course anyone can click "View Source" and read them).

If you're building your UI in JavaScript then your server-side code (can still be PHP, or any other language your host supports) just needs to be an  API which sends and receives data (probably in JSON format) rather than HTML. You may find you use AJAX requests a lot to send/receive data from the server, rather than full postbacks. This is quite a common architecture.

Comment: i am building my ui in javascript, react.js more specifically. so is it common for people to write their react projects with php server side code? with the API you mentioned, does the API communicate from javascript to PHP or from PHP to the database- and- are these API already in existence or do they need to be created by me?

Comment: if they have a database then it's essential to have some server-side code, yes. Whether it's in PHP or not is a separate decision. An API is just a concept. It's some server-side code which can receive a HTTP request and provide a response. It's exactly like a regular website except normally it deals in machine-readable data rather than user interface elements. In a regular website you return HTML in response to the user's request. In an API you return pure data. The most common format for the data these days is JSON, although some people use XML instead.

Comment: The flow would be that the JS code makes an AJAX request to the API, possibly passing in some data (e.g. a search term, for example). Then the API code queries the database, processes the result of the query and turns it into the dataset to return to the client. The client JS code then receives the data and uses it to alter the UI in some way (e.g. display search results). There are certainly frameworks available in PHP and other languages (e.g. Web API for ASP.NET) which will streamline the process of writing API-like code, you can search around online to find something which suits you.

Comment: in short: your react app (js, frontend) talks to API (backend, can be php connecting to db, files, mailserver, whatever) receiving response in json format - data usually is set in state (setState) forcing view update (rerendering)